# Is there any specific prayer (or mantra) to recite before eating food?

Tags: mantras, food, prayer, eating

We see in other religions that prayer after food is best, so is there any such in Hinduism? And if so, what is that particular Mantra or prayer?

Comment: The "Annapurne Sada Purne ..." mantra is usually chanted before eating food. Its a simple mantra that anyone can chant but there are others which are meant for Upanita persons .. see -- https://shlokam.org/annapurnesadapurne/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bhagavad Gita 9.27](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc420049.html) says:

> यत् करोषि यद् अश्नासि यज् जुहोषि ददासि यत् ।
> यत् तपस्यसि कौन्तेय तत् कुरुष्व मद्-अर्पणम् ॥ २७ ॥
>
> yat karoṣi yad aśnāsi yaj juhoṣi dadāsi yat |
> yat tapasyasi kaunteya tat kuruṣva mad-arpaṇam || 27 ||
>
> O son of Kuntī, whatever activities you perform, **whatever you eat**, whatever you sacrifice and give in charity and whatever austerities you perform, **offer them all to Me**.

So food should be offered to God before it is consumed.

One mantra you can use is the *Bhojan Mantra*, which comes from [Yajur Veda](https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/The-Yajur-Veda-Taittiriya-Sanhita-Taittiriya-Sanhita.pdf) 11.83:

> Om Annapate annasya no dehyana-meevasya shushminah,
> Pra pradaataaram taarish oorjam no dhehi dvipade chatushpade.
> Om Shantih, Shantih, Shantih !
>
> O Lord Provider of food grains, & all edibles, thanks you for giving us food today. May this food be decease-free and nourishing, and be it good for my body, mind & soul, I pray!
> O Benefactor of the donors & providers of food, may all living receive their sustenance every day!
> Peace be on all, everywhere, all times!

Comment: The offering of food to God, is that to be offered mentally or physically?

Comment: @Rajam - Before you eat, you should verbally offer the food to God before you begin to eat it. (Some traditions also include _naivedya_, where the platter is moved clockwise around a _diya_ / lamp three times)

Comment: #CDR is there a particular Mantra of offering to God or is the Mantra you have given enough for that?

Comment: @Rajam - the one in the answer is enough :)

Comment: thanks for the answer;)